# MySQL Workbench Creating Users and Privileges

Tags: schema, mysql-workbench, privileges, createuser

Can someone help. I have been going round in xcircles trying to solve a very basic issue, whith MySQL Workbench version 8.0.36. Runnung on MocOS Sona 14.2.1 I am trying to create new users for my  MySql Server and assign them appropriate privilegeas for relevant databases.

I am failing to follow the instructrion on the MySQL Wortkbenck help page:
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

Having navigate to the "Users and Privileges" dialogue. I have clicked on the "Add Account Button" and filled the "Login" tab as follows.

[Login Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAIZ.jpg)

And clicked the "Apply" button. I have left the "Account Limits" and the "Administrative Roles" tabs untounched (See below):

[Accountn Limits Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPGxV.jpg)

[Adninistrative Roles Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm5Ac.jpg)

Then I went to the "Schema Privileges" Tab:

[Schema Privileges Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmNYt.jpg)

And everything is eisabled. The Help  Pages say :

> Add a schema entry (or rule) that specifies which schema or schemas apply the selected user account. Click Add Entry to open the New Schema Privilege Definition dialog.

But I cannot find the "Add Entrty" button anywhere. I have look in all the menus, I have clicked, dobble clicked and right clicked under Schema. I have looked fort a physocal button. So I gave up an logged into my Ubuntu server and created the user in MYSQL command line. What am I doing wrong?

See the description above.

Answer (score 1):

For me, MySQL Workbench was a complete disaster (Kubuntu 22.04). Dropdown buttons regularly did not work, keywords and other placeholders were not inserted into generated scripts (like field names on creating a foreign key!), so I would  recommend trying it in a different SQL GUI, or via CLI interface. I know this does not really solves your issue, since I cannot provide a solution on Workbench, and I just recommend to abandon it as soon as you can.

DBeaver works fine for me, you should give it a try.

Comment: What GUI do you use?

Comment: I use DBeaver. It's kinda cool, however some stuff might be "uncomfortable" after switching from MySQL